# Angular reactive forms turn formgroup into null form control

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a formgroup:

```
(<FormArray>this.myForm.get('rooms')).push(this.fBuilder.group({
                id: [element.id, [Validators.required]],
                foreground: this.fBuilder.group({
            foregroundImageUpload: [null],
            foregroundImageID: [background.foregroundImageID, [Validators.required]],
            foregroundImagePath: [background.foregroundImagePath, [Validators.required]]
        })
            }));
```

But later I want to remove the formgroup and set it to null. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
this.myForm.controls.rooms['controls'][roomIndex].removeControl('foreground');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "methods" of [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) and [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray), don't work directly over controls.

In your case:

```
//In steps:
const array=this.myForm.get('rooms') as FormArray //use 'get' to access a control
                                                  //or a formGroup/Formarray
const group=array.at(index)   //use 'at' to access the formGroup of the FormArray
group.removeControl('foreground') //use 'removeControl'

//in a unique line
(this.myForm.get('rooms') as FormArray).at(index)
    .removeControl('foreground')
```